# Android Studio rendering Error

Tags: android, xml, android-studio

So I just tried to render one of my xml views and I got this error:

```
Exception raised during rendering: Binary XML file line #-1: No start tag found!
```

Any ideas? I've included the manifest file below______________________________
manifest:

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.adrian.trucktracker">
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_INTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"/>

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/legionicon"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
        >
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".Locator"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_locator" >
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: Try removing the space from the first line in your manifest

Comment: there is no space, thats just the way stackoverflow presented it

Comment: i fixed it, just close android studio and open it again

Answer (score 22):

Since I cannot comment yet, I'm posting this as a reply. 
This seems to be a bug in Android Studio where when you edit the xml file directly, it doesn't update in it's graphical layout yet. The issue has been raised and I don't think it has been corrected yet. Here's [the issue](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?can=2&start=0&num=100&q=&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Owner%20Summary%20Stars&groupby=&sort=&id=57712) for you to upvote.

For now, though you don't need to restart the entire Android Studio. Just close the tab and reopen it from the project navigation pane. It'll load correctly. It'll save you a lot of time.

Comment: This bug still exists in Android 1.5.1. Close and reopen tab is not an option  :/

Answer (score 0):

Closing the tab was quite dramatic for me since I had very very many files in my project.

Moving the problematic tab between different split views did the trick in a second.